# PHP browser game energy recover time

Tags: php, browser

I would like to create something very simple. A browser game, where user can waste its energy and ability points. Unlike other games here there won't be no levels. So energy and ability points restore with the time.

How can I do that in the most efficient way? 
For example, i have 100 energy points, one point restores every 2 min.

I was thinking about cron-jobs, but that will be not so efficient.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling game-state updates in an MMO while the player is logged out](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83666/handling-game-state-updates-in-an-mmo-while-the-player-is-logged-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web php games usally uses 2 different ways to do this:

1- Daemon. You set up a "run forever" script that sleeps for 1 second and updates all data that needs update.

2- Time elapsed. you have to store the last conection somewhere and, in the next connection do CURRENTTIMESTAMP - LASTTIMESTAMP to get the seconds elapsed since last update, so you just have to multiply your resources by second by the seconds elapsed.

Depending on your needs you can use, one or another or both.

Comment: I would say that using a PHP Daemon like you said, is nearly impossible, because no webhost will allow a forever-running script...

Comment: lot of webhosts gives you ssh access, that's all you need to set up a daemon, you should read what's a daemon and how does it work before responding

Comment: I know what a deamon is, I didn't know that you could use SSH on webhosts, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: sorry, i wasn't trying to attack you , my answer was really offensive... normally, if you want to build this kind of game you has to rent a dedicated server, so you have acces to the whole system

Comment: Don't worry ;). So for example a VPS won't do it?

Comment: It could but if you want to manage lot of users and/or game worlds you will need more CPU, RAM and HDD than you can cheaply have in a shared server.

Anyways, is rare to find a VPS provider that allows you to run ssh but there are some, for example you have 1and1, or some instances of godaddy, but i would recomend using openshift or amazon WPS, it's cheap, escalable and easy to set up.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start with daemon and see where it will get me